# Triggering on beforeunload using jQuery 1.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I need to listen to `beforeunload` in jQuery 1.3.

In Jquery 1.4, I can use

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){ ... });
```

Since bind method is not available in jQuery 1.3, what are my options to listen to this event?

Comment: $(body).on('beforeunload', function(){ ... }); is not working ?

Comment: @user1073122 `.on` was not introduced until jQuery 1.7

Comment: In the jquery documentation, I can see that .bind( eventType [, eventData ], handler(eventObject) ) is added on the version 1.0